# Dataframes can be edited by direct assignment in R?

Tags: r

I want to edit the exising datafrane. Can I edit using direct assignment?

```
first = c("c","c++","java")
second = c("sql","oracle","mongodb")

df=data.frame(first,second)
```

Now I want to edit it using direct assignment or whichever is simpler 
like

```
df[[1]][2]="hello"
```

But it is showing an error as:

> Warning message: In '[<-.factor'('*tmp*', 3, value = c(3L, 2L, NA)) : 
>   invalid factor level, NA generated

can someone explain me this?

Comment: `df = data.frame(first, second, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: To clarify @Roland's comment, `data.frame()` will convert character vectors to factor columns by default.  You can avoid this by specifying the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Comment: data_frame = data.frame(first,second,third,stringAsFactors = FALSE)
                                                                                            data_frame[[1]][3] ="hello"     is it correct way to write?

Comment: please tell me right  way to write it  the  code in above comment by me is totally wrong. It is creating the new column entry

Comment: It's `stringsAsFactors` (you are missing one '**s**')

Comment: Thanks Roland,Nathan & prem